# How to make notepad++ go to the next line when make curly brackets

Tags: notepad++

(I'm using XBracketsLite with c#)
this is what notepad++ does

```
void voidName(){

}
```

what i want it to do

```
void voidName()
{

}
```

Comment: XBrackletsLite is not coded in c#, but in c++. Anyway, You should either configure the notepad++ plugin (if that is possible) or modify its code to get the behavior you want. If you do the later, and have problems doing it, edit your question and add a [mcve] of the code that you have problems with

Comment: You should ask XBracketsLite developpers. This question is offtopic on SO.